# A classic trigonometry question.

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin x- \cos x= \frac {1}{2}$;
$\sin^3 x- \cos^3 x =$ ?

Comment: I have edited the question with mathjax.  You should include your attempts for a favourable response.

Comment: $\sin 2x=\frac34$ on the other hand $\sin^3 x- \cos^3 x=(\sin x-\cos x)^3+\frac{3}{2}\sin 2x(\sin x-\cos x)=\frac {11}{16}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sin x - cos x = $\frac12$

Squaring both sides,

$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x - 2 \sin x \cos x = \frac 14$

$1 - 2 \sin x \cos x = \frac 14$

$- 2 \sin x \cos x = \frac 14 - 1$

$- 2 \sin x \cos x = - \frac 34$

$\sin x \cos x = \frac 38$

Now $\sin^3 x - \cos^3 x$

= $(\sin x-\cos x)(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x+\sin x \cos x)$

= $\left( \frac12 \right) \left(1 + \frac38\right)$

= $\left( \frac12 \right) \left( \frac{11}8\right)$

= $\left( \frac{11}{16}\right) $

Comment: Your answer easiest for me in the all answer, but it is not true answer. Thanks.

Comment: @K You made a mistake: $$-2\sin x\cos x=-\frac34\implies \sin x\cos x=\frac38$$

Comment: @DonAntonio thank u. My main problem is I am used mobile to solve so some time typos.

Comment: Yes I realised your mistake and fixed it:) Your answer is best for me :)

Comment: Mine pleasure..

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x -\cos x=\frac12$$
$$\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x=\frac14$$
$$\sin x\cos x=?$$

Also 
$$\sin^3 x- \cos^3 x =(\sin x-\cos x)(\sin^2x+\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x)=?$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\sin(x)-\cos(x)=-\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)$$

Comment: How do you proceed after that? You have $\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: we have $$x-\frac{\pi}{4}=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{11}{16}$$

Comment: Because $\sin x$ is not $1-1$, we cannot simply take the inverse of this function on both sides without losing generality.

Comment: do you actually compute every possible value of sin(x) and cos(x)? It's a bit long but certainly yields the result.

Comment: yes but i have not squared the given equation!

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. sin(x) = y, has multiple solutions for x without squaring. E.g: sin(0)=sin($2\pi$)=0.

Comment: The general solution of $sin(x)=t, 0\leq t\leq 1$ is $x = (-1)^n(2n+1)*\frac{\pi}{2}+sin^{-1}t$ where $sin^{-1}t$ denotes the value between $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ Good luck expanding that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Note the following:
$$\sin^3(x)-\cos^3(x)=(\sin(x)-\cos(x))(1+\sin(x)\cos(x))$$
And
$$(\sin(x)-\cos(x))^2=\sin^2(x)-2\sin(x)\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)=1-2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac{1}{4}$$